# ERROR: Repository not found message given when following the instructions for Jekyll-Bootstrap (push origin master)

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

Github pages not working for me when using Jekyll-Bootstrap.
I followed the instructions here:
http://jekyllbootstrap.com/

The instructions say:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap.git USERNAME.github.com
$ cd USERNAME.github.com
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/USERNAME.github.com.git
$ git push origin master
```

I used the personalized install code (means my github name rather than "USERNAME")
I get this error when I try to do the last "$ git push origin master"

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

How do I get this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a repo on GitHub called "USERNAME.github.com".